# Comparing AIC for different types of models (beta and normal)

Tags: r, statistics, model-comparison

I have responses which are proportions mainly centered around 0.6-0.7, and not many of them are close to 0 or 1. I have tried fitting both normal and beta models, and the normal models yield lower AIC than the beta models. I use the lm package for fitting the normal model, and betareg for the beta model. 
But I wonder it if it really possible to compare AIC values for different model types like that? I do of course use the same response variables and the same data for both regressions.

Note: I tried to read about Kullback-Leibler divergence here: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4049836 (name: The AIC Criterion and Symmetrizing the Kullback–Leibler Divergence), but got confused by this sentence on page two: "It is also assumed as in [12] that the search is carried out in a parametric family of distribution including the true model.", where [12] refers to Akaikes article from 1974. Does this imply that I cannot compare the AIC from a beta and a normal model, as the true model cannot be both beta and normal?
Note 2: I tried to logit-transform the responses and then fit a normal model, but that just made the residual plots look worse.

Comment: I'm voting to migrate to [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Did you find an anwer, @SummerRed? I'm stuck with the same question; edit: would it be ok if I ask the question in Cross-Validated?

Comment: Of course! I asked my professor, and she advised not to do to it, but I got the impression that it was because she was not sure either (I did not get an explanation) - would've been interesting to find out:)